# Map an Array by every two elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

Lets say I have an array of services objects

```
services: [{title: title, caption: caption},{title: title, caption: caption},{title: title, caption: caption},{title: title, caption: caption}]
```

The end result is a mapped array with every two elements in it's own div.

```
<div>
 <div>services[0]</div>
 <div>services[1]</div>
</div>
<div>
 <div>services[2]</div>
 <div>services[3]</div>
</div>
```

I cant wrap my head around how I would achieve this?  Map and split the array by every two elements?  Split the array into two arrays, then map that? Is it to early in the morning?  Yes it is.

Comment: How are you creating the html?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, one way to do it is to group the array by every two elements, but you'd do that by using `reduce`.

The callback for `reduce` [can actually take four arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and you can initialize the accumulator with an empty array, so it ends up looking like this:

```js
const services = [{
  title: 'title0',
  caption: 'caption0'
}, {
  title: 'title1',
  caption: 'caption1'
}, {
  title: 'title2',
  caption: 'caption2'
}, {
  title: 'title3',
  caption: 'caption3'
}];

services
  .reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
    if (currentIndex % 2 === 0) {
      accumulator.push(array.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + 2));
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, [])
  .forEach(p => console.log(p[0], p[1]));
```

Comment: @OmamaZainab the intention is to split the array into pairs, so I'm not sure what it would mean for it to "work" if the array had an odd number of items.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `for` loop that increments by 2 and inside `map` method to create string and after add it to html.

```js
const data = [{title: 'title', caption: 'caption'},{title: 'title', caption: 'caption'},{title: 'title', caption: 'caption'},{title: 'title', caption: 'caption'}, {title: 'title', caption: 'caption'}]

let html = '';
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
  const divs = data
    .slice(i, i + 2)
    .map(({title, caption}) => `<div>${title} | ${caption}</div>`)
    .join('')
    
  html += `<div>${divs}</div>`;
}

document.body.innerHTML += html;
```

Comment: Is it possible for some values of the array to be missed if the length is not an odd number?

Answer (score 2):

Use (index % 2) to close and open the new div.

```js
var array = [
 {title: 'title', caption: 'caption'},
 {title: 'title', caption: 'caption'},
 {title: 'title', caption: 'caption'},
 {title: 'title', caption: 'caption'},
 {title: 'title', caption: 'caption'},
 {title: 'title', caption: 'caption'}
]

var html = '<div class="row">'
array.forEach(function (item, index) {
 html += '<div>' + item.title + '</div>'
 html += '<div>' + item.caption + '</div>'
 if (index % 2) {
  html += '</div><div class="row">'
 }
})

html += '</div>'

document.getElementById('result').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
```

```css
.row {
 margin: 20px 0px;
 background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the items in groups of two ...

```js
var services = [
    {title: 'title1', caption: 'caption1'},
    {title: 'title2', caption: 'caption2'},
    {title: 'title3', caption: 'caption3'},
    {title: 'title4', caption: 'caption4'}
];

for (var i = 0; i < services.length; i += 2) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div><div>' + services[i].title + '</div>' + 
                             '<div>' + services[i + 1].title + '</div></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For information about possible solutions and namings - you can use [splitEvery method from Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#splitEvery)